# Minimum principle of superharmonic functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I want to prove the following:

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain and $u:C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\overline{\Omega}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a superharmonic function, i.e. $-\Delta u \geq 0$.

Then, it satisfies the minimum principle: 
$\displaystyle\min_{\overline{\Omega}}u = \displaystyle\min_{\partial{\Omega}}u$.

I have previously proven the mean value inequality for $u$, which I think I'll have to use:

For all $x \in \Omega$ and $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subset \Omega$, it holds that: $$\displaystyle u(x) \geq \frac{1}{|\partial{B(x,r)}|}\int_{\partial{B(x,r)}} u \ dS $$

I tried to start with considering a point $x_0$ s.t. $u(x_0) = \displaystyle\min_{\overline{\Omega}}u = \mu $.

Then for any $0<r< dist(x_0, \partial{\Omega})$, we have:

$\mu = \displaystyle u(x_0) \geq \frac{1}{|\partial{B(x_0,r)|}}\int_{\partial{B(x_0,r)}} u(y) \ dS(y) \geq \mu $.

This inequality holds for any $0 < r' \leq r$ and hence the continuity of $u$ implies that $u(y) = u(x_0)= \mu$ for all $y \in B(x_0,r)$.

Can you give me a hint on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, we should note that $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb R^n$ which you omit there.

---

It’s the weak minimum principle, we have two different ways to prove it.

### First way :

Firstly, we consider the case $-\Delta u>0$ in $\Omega $. If there is a $x_0\in\Omega$ such that $$u(x_0)=\min_{\bar\Omega}u(x).$$
By necessity for extreme values, we know that the hessian matrix at $x_0$ is semi-positive definite, which means
$$-\Delta u(x_0)\leq 0.$$
It’s a contradiction. That is $$\displaystyle\min_{\bar{\Omega}}u = \displaystyle\min_{\partial{\Omega}}u.$$
Generally, for the case $-\Delta u\geq 0$  we define for $\forall \epsilon>0$
$$v(x)=u(x)-\epsilon|x|^2\quad in\,\Omega.$$
Hence, we obtain
$$-\Delta v=-\Delta(u-\epsilon|x|^2)=-\Delta u+2n\epsilon>0.$$
Thus
$$\displaystyle\min_{\bar{\Omega}}v= \displaystyle\min_{\partial{\Omega}}v.$$
Note that
$$\min_{\bar\Omega}u\geq \min_{\bar\Omega}v=\min_{\partial\Omega}v\geq\min_{\partial\Omega}u -\epsilon \max_{\partial\Omega}|x|^2.$$
Let $\epsilon\to 0$ yields
$$\min_{\bar\Omega}u\geq\min_{\partial\Omega}u$$
since $\Omega$ is bounded. And it’s clear that
$$\min_{\bar\Omega}u\leq\min_{\partial\Omega}u$$
which gives us
$$\min_{\bar\Omega}u =\min_{\partial\Omega}u.$$

### Second way :

In this part, we will use mean value inequality.

Let $m:=\min_\limits{\bar\Omega}u$ and $D:=\{x\in\Omega: u(x)=m\}$. It’s clear that D is relative closed to $\Omega$. Next, we will prove D is relative open.

For $x_0\in D$, by mean value inequality we know
$$m= \displaystyle u(x_0) \geq \frac{1}{|\partial{B(x_0,r)|}}\int_{\partial{B(x_0,r)}} u(y) \ dS(y) \geq m$$for any $0<r< dist(x_0, \partial{\Omega})$,
which yields $u(y) = u(x_0)= m$ for all $y \in B(x_0,r)$.

Thus $B(x_0,r)\subset D$, that is D is relative open.And since $\Omega$ is connected, we get $D=\Omega$ or $D=\phi$.

Hence, we know
$$\min_{\bar\Omega} u=\min_{\partial\Omega} u.$$

---

If you want to learn more about maximal principle, we refer you to Han Qing and Lin Fanghua’s elliptic pde.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it is very helpful.